# How to draw stacked column chart with custom text fields?

Tags: reporting, ms-project-2013

I am working on a *report* on MS Project 2013. In this report there is **chart**.

The chart is based :

- *NumberOftasks* (Y-axis) which is a custom field of type number.
- *Localization* (X-axis) which is done by *Grouping* the tasks by localization (it is a custom text field).

The awkward situation is that I have a custom field  of type text, called **typeOftask** which take two values : either A or B.

I would like to draw *clustered column* chart that take in consideration the *typeOfTask* so that the column is divided into two values : the number of tasks of type A and the number of tasks of type B.

Something like this : 
[image]

Please, how to do that in MS Project 2013 ? I know it is possible ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear.  You have 2 or three custom fields?  Number of tasks which is a number field with a formula?  A count?
What is localization?  A text field?  And you've grouped by the field?  
And to that, you want it further broken down by A & B?
What relationship does the number of tasks have to A & B?
Have you tried modifying your group to group first by Localisation and then by Type of Task?

Comment: I have three custom fields : *NumberOfTasks, Localisation, and typeOfTask* , *NumberOfTask* is a Number (for each task I put 1 and get the count of tasks by sum in summary tasks).

Comment: *localization* is a custom field that contains cities .... it is Text custom field. I grouped the tasks by *Localization*. When I group by *Localization* and *typeOfTask* I don't get a modified chart, rather the axis that is modified if you know what i mean.

Comment: Right, I have that part (and you can just use the Count command for the calculation for group or summary rows.)

I've done a quick experiment and can't seem to the get second level group (group by Localisation then by type) to show in the chart.

Comment: I have this as result : http://imgur.com/UJCzQuR

Comment: I want this : http://imgur.com/1WiuQJX

Comment: or better this : http://blog.visual.ly/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/StackedPercent.png

Comment: Project is not Excel.  As I stated, I can't get the second level group to work.  I do not know if it is possible.  Were either of your charts created in Project?

Comment: the first one created in MS Project 2013, the others found on the net ...

Comment: Again - I don't believe this is possible.  The second level grouping does not seem to carry to the chart.  You certainly can create two charts - one showing the count by Localisation and another showing count by Type.

Comment: Ok. Since it is impossible. Do I keep this question or delete it ?

Comment: Up to you.  I'd keep it just in case others have the same question.